# IE11 width calc() not evaluating in border & padding when using inline-table or inline-block

Tags: css, layout

I am having an issue with IE11 and utilizing the CSS calc() function along with `display: inline-block` and/or `display: inline-table`.

Currently I have a text input and a button that should be next to each other (inline), with the button always being a fixed width and the input should take up the available space leftover (i.e. `calc(100% - 92px)`). Both elements are `display: inline-table;`. In all other browsers, doing this `calc()` worked fine. In IE11, it drops the button to the next line.

<strike>Included in the JSBin are a couple styles at the bottom that make the elements appear inline, although this fix will not work for an end result. What I did was added `display:inline-block` to both the input & button and also removed `padding` and `border` from the input. At the end of the day, the input **must have padding & border` so this will not work for my use case.</strike>

^^ `box-sizing: border-box` fixed that "hack", but the issue as a whole still exists in IE11.

[**Here is the JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/loxucoz/edit?html,css,output) (in order to see the issue, you must be using IE11)

The CSS, as it stands now, looks like this...

```
body, dd, figure, form {
    margin: 0;
}

form {
    margin-top: 1.6875rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

form fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
}

input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

input {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 4px 12px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 6px 0 14px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;    
    width: calc(100% - 92px);
    height: 40px;
}

button {
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 92px;
}
```

I'm assuming there is a bug with IE11 and `calc()` in which `calc()` doesn't take into account the border/padding when an element is `display:inline-block` or `display:inline-table`, although I could not find anything in my research to suggest this 100%.

Ultimately my question is, how do I get two elements to be "inline" with one being a fixed pixel value and the other a percentage width that is cross browser compliant.

**EDIT:** added `box-sizing: border-box` which made the `display: inline` and `padding/border: 0` obsolete at the bottom of the JSBin. The issue still persists in IE11 though.

Comment: Why not use `box-sizing: border-box;` ?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith good call! I totally forgot about that. That fixed the issue so that I do not need to worry about resetting the padding/border & making it inline-block, but the issue still exists in IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is as follows...

As Adam mentioned in the comments above, adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to, at the very least, the input & button elements fixed the issue where the border/padding was not being calculated in the `calc()` function.

In addition to that, changing `display: inline-table` to `display: inline-block` fixed the issue in IE11.